# Парсинг стены вконтакта через АПИ, как решить проблему ограничения на кол-во запрашиваемых постов?

Tags: vkontakte-api

Метод wall.get
Возвращает список записей со стены пользователя или сообщества.
Но у него ограничение - максимум 100 постов.

В обычном цикле сделать не получается. Видимо надо применять асинхронные запросы?

Плиз, куда копать, чем это сделать?

Comment: делайте запросы раз в 0.3 секунды и всё......ну плюс есть метод `execute` в котором можно сделать несколько циклов, а значит выбрать около 1000 записей за раз

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используйте метод [`execute`](https://vk.com/dev/execute). Он позволяет вызывать методы VK API до 25 раз за один вызов. Вы пишете код на кастрированном и строгом JavaScript, он обрабатывается серверами ВКонтакте и результат выполнения отдается вам.

Работать с этим методом можно двумя способами:

1. Через хранимые процедуры. То есть код процедуры будет храниться в настойках вашего приложения ВКонтакте.
2. Обращаясь к методу `execute` напрямую, передавая в него сгенерированный код.

### Хранимые процедуры

Как создать хранимую процедуру?

1. Перейдите в настройки приложения.
2. Откройте вкладку "Хранимые процедуры".
3. Нажмите кнопку "Добавить новую процедуру".
4. Дайте имя процедуре над полем ввода кода — затем ее можно будет использовать как обычный метод API. Если вы дадите процедуре имя `foo`, то ее можно будет вызвать как метод `execute.foo`.
5. Напишите код процедуры.

[image: Метод execute]

Например, таким вызовом можно получить 500 записей со стены за раз:

```
var offset   = Args.offset;
var owner_id = Args.owner_id;

return
    API.wall.get({
        "owner_id" : owner_id,
        "count"    : 100,
        "filter"   : "owner",
        "offset"   : parseInt(offset) + 0 * 100
    }).items + 
    API.wall.get({
        "owner_id" : owner_id,
        "count"    : 100,
        "filter"   : "owner",
        "offset"   : parseInt(offset) + 1 * 100
    }).items +
    API.wall.get({
        "owner_id" : owner_id,
        "count"    : 100,
        "filter"   : "owner",
        "offset"   : parseInt(offset) + 2 * 100
    }).items + 
    API.wall.get({
        "owner_id" : owner_id,
        "count"    : 100,
        "filter"   : "owner",
        "offset"   : parseInt(offset) + 3 * 100
    }).items +
    API.wall.get({
        "owner_id" : owner_id,
        "count"    : 100,
        "filter"   : "owner",
        "offset"   : parseInt(offset) + 4 * 100
    }).items;
```

У этого метода есть довольно жесткие ограничения по потреблению памяти, поэтому не всегда получится использовать его на полную катушку. Например, именно по этой причине я не использовал цикл, а сделал колхозный вызов 5 методов подряд. Почему 5 запросов к API, а не 25? Причина та же — если записи будут слишком большими, то вызвать цепочку методов не получится и запрос отвалится с ошибкой *response size is too big*, поэтому следует быть менее жадным. На этом скриншоте я попробовал получить 2500 записей со стены сообщества, где публикуются длинные истории:

[image: Ошибка response size is too big]

### Прямой вызов `execute`

Можно не создавать хранимые процедуры, а генерировать код для метода `execute` динамически. Для этого код следует передавать в параметре `code`, обращаясь к методу `execute`. Практической разницы в использовании хранимых процедур и прямых вызовов метода `execute` нет; это дело вкуса, но лично я предпочитаю именно хранимые процедуры из-за возможности удобного кроссплатформенного и повторного использования.

Если вы не понимаете, что я подразумеваю под «обращаться к методу `execute`», то вот пример обычного запроса на PHP:

```
$parameters = [
    'code'         => 'return 123;', // код процедуры
    'v'            => '5.60',
    'access_token' => 'asdadarwerwe'
];

echo file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/execute?'.http_build_query($parameters));
```

Этот вызов выведет вам на экран JSON-строку такого содержания:

```
{
  "response": 123
}
```

### Об ограничениях

На `execute` (и, собственно, хранимые процедуры тоже) также распространяется ограничение на 3 обращения к API в секунду. То есть, если вы будете вызывать этот метод чаще трех раз в секунду, то будет существовать вероятность нарваться на ошибку, сообщающую о том, что вы обращаетесь к API слишком часто. В таком случае имеет смысл только настроить логику своего приложения так, чтобы оно делало задержку перед обращением к API, если достигнут лимит по запросам.