# Vk запрос к стене группы

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Разрабатываю приложение, которое будет обращаться к стене группы раз в секунду

Делал через api, группа сама закрытая

Пока я пользовался им один - все было нормально

Но как только появились тестировщики со стороны - естественно посыпались ограничения в вк на количество запросов

Вопроса два:

1) Можно ли с помощью метода execute выдавать контент стены периодически, например раз в секунду и какие ограничения там стоят? (в документации не нашел)

2) Может все же существуют какие-то законные способы кроме api?

Comment: 1) Нет - вcегда будут лимиты, 2) Нет

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/610592/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%90%D0%9F%D0%98-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF

Comment: @Arsen И что же делать?
не может быть, чтоб нельзя было создать подобное приложение

Comment: Лучше скажите зачем вам обращаться к VK каждую секунду ? что вы делаете своим приложением ?  "выдавать контент стены периодически" - каждую секунду... это не переодически, это атака ))

Comment: @Arsen Мне нужно почти мгновенно среагировать на выход каждого нового поста в группе

Comment: Насколько помню у вк в апи нет возможности получения 'сигнала" когда  постят, а это значит что остается только метод запроса для проверки (у которого и лимиты), думаю зря теряеет время (запросы каждую секунду) лучше проверяете есть ли новый пост, каждые 30 сек или 40 сек

Comment: @Arsen К сожалению, для меня этого не достаточно, необходимо быстрее

Comment: @Arsen я придумал, как можно решить эту проблему. Можно создать штук 40 приложений для api vk, для каждого создать бесконечный токен и поочередно их использовать

Comment: У ВК есть [Callback API](https://vk.com/dev/callback_api), который позволяет получать уведомления о новых постах мгновенно

Comment: @andreymal А как создать подходящий сервер?

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать штук 40 приложений для api vk, для каждого создать бесконечный токен и поочередно их использовать

Comment: Все равно не помогло, может кому-то и поможет, но у меня особая ситуация