# Как получить больше 1000 фото из альбома VK?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Имею код, с которого успешно получаю 1000 фотографий:

```
import requests
import json
```

token = '57c13777775ttt3e03034c70a14e3b77c26b36ttttrt3096c33008543b589f'
id = '00000007'

def write_json(data):
with open('photos.json', 'w') as file:
json.dump(data, file, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)

def main():
r = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/photos.get', params={'owner_id':id,'access_token':token,'rev':0,'extended':1,'album_id':'saved','count':1000,'photo_sizes': True, 'v':5.21})

`write_json(r.json())`

Позже пишу код для выделения одной ссылки на вариант фотографии наибольшего размера, получаю ссылку, скачиваю фотографии. Всё получается.
Но у меня в альбоме 10200 фотографий. Как реализовать решение, которое бы получало ссылки на все эти 10200 фотографии в альбоме и желательно в хронологическом порядке, а не только на 1000?

Comment: похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/610592/Парсинг-стены-вконтакта-через-АПИ-как-решить-проблему-ограничения-на-кол-во-зап

Достаточно использовать метод execute

Comment: Очевидно, менять параметр offset

Comment: в params изменять count на 10200 не пробовали?

Comment: Используйте метод execute. Получилось скачать с помощью него. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/610592/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%90%D0%9F%D0%98-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF (Данилкин)